# Why are there times of prayer

Tags: tefilla, time

There are many times of prayer.
Why? 
Is this a  teaching made to make order?
Anything to do with the Cosmos?

In the psalms King David also has morning prayer.

Morning, afternoon, midnight, why not whenever?

**Why is there a system for prayer during the day?**

Answer (score 3):

[Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/qorbanot.htm) says

> In Jewish practice, prayer has taken the place of sacrifices. In
>   accordance with the words of Hosea, we render instead of bullocks the
>   offering of our lips (Hosea 14:3). Our prayer services are in many
>   ways designed to parallel the sacrificial practices. For example, we
>   have an extra service on Shabbat, to parallel the extra Shabbat
>   offering.

There were two daily offerings, morning and afternoon.

> "The one lamb you shall offer up in the morning, and the other lamb
>   you shall offer up in the afternoon." [see Bamidbar 28: 1-8 especially
>   4,](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9956)

and the limbs and fat pieces of the offerings were left on the altar at night,

> "Burning the fats and limbs [of the sacrifices, on the Temple altar] —
>   their precepts [can be performed] until the break of dawn." see
>   [Mishna Berochos 1
>   (1).](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.1?lang=en)

Comment: So prayer is seen as an offering,interesting.Can I ask Is singing worship  an offering?

Comment: Prayer has **replaced** offerings; prayer is not an offering itself. You should ask a separate question about singing. Do you mean, is the singing (as well as the recitation) of the prayers a replacement of the offering?

Comment: "prayer is not an offering itself." I think you did answer my question. But when you say replacment,are you saying when they did offer Lamb there was no need for prayer?

Comment: No, they prayed also.

Answer (score 2):

Two explanations are given in the talmud, B'rachot 26b:

- After the destruction of the Temple, prayer replaced the *korbanot* (offerings) that were brought.  Those offerings were brought at specific times, and we align our prayer times with them.  We're talking here specifically about the *Amidah*, the central prayer of each service.  (You might ask: they brought offerings at night?  The evening prayer corresponds to the burning of the last offering, which happened overnight.)
- Our sages understand that each of our three patriarchs instituted one of the prayers -- Avraham the morning prayer (*shacharit*), Yitzchak the afternoon prayer (*mincha*), and Yaakov the evening prayer (*maariv*).  This approach does not fix the times as closely as the one tied to *korbanot*, and does not address the *musaf* prayer.

In addition to these fixed prayer times (and themes/texts), people can pray personal prayers at other times.

Comment: The Yerushalmi (Berakhot 4:1) adds a third option: three times the sun changes [direction?] each warrant a prayer for protection during that time: after sunrise, after noon, and after sunset.