# Why do we add ותערב and why only in Musaf?

Tags: tefilla, yom-tov, shacharis-morning-prayer, birchas-kohanim, musaf

On Yom Tov (usually during the repetition of the Amida in Musaf) the Kohanim ascend to bless the people. In preparation, the congregation (and Kohanim and the chazzan) say a paragraph after R'tzei which reads (with some slight variation IIRC)

> ותערב לפניך עתירתנו כעולה וכקרבן.
>   אנא רחום ברחמיך הרבים השב שכינתך לציון עירך וסדר העבודה לירושלים.

This translates to (according to the Artscroll Sukkot Machzor)

> May our entreaty be pleasing unto You as an elevation-offering and as a sacrifice. Please, O Merciful One, in your abounding mercy return Your Shechina to Zion, You city, and the order of the Temple service to Jerusalem.

Then we continue with V'techezena. In terms of content it speaks of restoring the sacrificial service and the allowance that prayer replaces sacrifice as mentioned in the R'tzei in all of our prayers.

Because this introduces duchening, I would assume that the "entreaty" referred to is the priestly blessing and that, like prayer itself taking the [place](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76548/1362) of sacrifice, we would like this prayer (or maybe, some other entreaty in the Amida which we make) to be as pleasing as a sacrifice.

I'm not sure why we need this intro to duchening in general but also wonder why then we don't need it when we duchen in the shacharit service of Simchat Torah [as per the Kitzur, 138:8 סעיף ח
ביום שמחת תורה נוהגין בהרבה מקומות שהכהנים נושאים כפיהם בתפלת שחרית ולא במוסף משום דבמוסף יש חשש שכרות, ואין אומרים ותערב בתפלת שחרית copied from [here](http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1650&ArticleID=7227).]

What does the paragraph mean or accomplish that it is called for before duchening and why is that need absent in Shacharit?

Comment: Is this practiced in Israel or only in the diaspora?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was wondering that. They duchen more often in Israel but I don't know the specifics of the practice. I can get that info with a phone call but I'm not sure that it would resolve the diaspora answer.

Comment: According to Artscroll's commentary, it's meant to be a call to those Kohanim to come duchan, as if they aren't up on the duchan by Modim they can't duchan. So the question becomes why they don't need such an invitation on Simchas Torah.

Comment: @DonielF I heard today about a local shul that duchened on Simchat Torah in Musaf. I have to find out whether, if they really did, they said vteiarev first, so I can see if this is a shacharis vs. musaf question or a Simchas Torah vs. other Y"T issue.

Comment: Come to think of it, you might want to look into when it's said in Eretz Yisrael, where they duchan at every single chazaras hashatz.

Comment: @DonielF They don't at Mincha (except at fast days that don't have Neilah). Probably more interesting is to check old Machzorim from where they still Duchened at Neilah in Chutz LaAretz.

Comment: @Danno The Shuls I've seen on Simchas Torah in the Diaspora who Duchen at Musaf do indeed say ותערב.

Comment: Just a quick check (from siddurim...people sleeping in E"Y) Chazon Ovadiah has no v'tei'arev in daily, shabbat or Y"T at all, and neither does Tehillat Hashem (Nusach Ari). The Siddur Hashalem Kol Bo and The Rinat Yisrael (for Israel) - bth Ashkenazi - have duchening every day and each Shabbat and Y"T but only have v'tei'arev on Y"T musaf.

Comment: @DonielF "if they aren't up on the duchan by Modim they can't duchan" That is simply wrong. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97_%D7%97

Comment: @DoubleAA You are right. That's what I meant to say, but that's not what I said, that they have to have begun going up to the Duchan by Modim.

Comment: @Danno did that Shul that duchened in Musaph have a Kiddush before Musaph?

Comment: @user613 I have to find out. I was caught off guard when I heard this so research is needed.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47886&st=&pgnum=135

Comment: @GershonGold Thank you -- I read it and see some difficulties but it is a start.

Comment: Apparently the text mentions "olah and korban" and (according to the Artscroll book on Birchat Kohanim) the olah might be a refrence to a tamid, but korban is a reference to korban musaf, making the text inappropriate for a non-musaf setting.

Comment: A [maḥzor from pre-expulsion England](http://opensiddur.org/?p=13834) seems to have ותערב in every prayer (on the right column of page 32 [here](https://archive.org/stream/SederTefilahFromTheEtzHayyimJacobJehudahHazzanOfLondon1287/Seder%20Tefilah%20from%20the%20Etz%20Hayyim%20%28Jacob%20Jehudah%20Hazzan%20of%20London%2C%201287%29#page/n31/mode/1up)).

Comment: @magicker72, they still duchened whenever ברכת כהנים was recited

Comment: According to Minhag Frankfurt, ותערב is added whenever we duchen on yom tov

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt What's your point? The shmoneh esreh written there is intended for *every* weekday prayer, including ones without duchening. This can be found in a few other places, like a manuscript of Machzor Vitry.

Answer (score 1):

[*Chevel Nachalato* 18:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%92) discusses this. In short, he says that these added lines may serve as a reminder to the Kohanim to ascend to the duchan, and for this reason some do recite them in Shacharit if Birkat Kohanim will be said:

> עדויות למנהג זה יש לפנינו גם מזמן מהר"ם מרוטנברג (ספר מנהגים דבי מהר"ם
>   ראש השנה ד"ה ואין אומ') ובני דורו (ספר המנהגים חילדיק3) ואחריהם בספר
>   המנהגים (טירנא4) ואחריהם במהרי"ל כמובא בספר מהרי"ל (מנהגים, הלכות
>   תפילת יום טוב ד"ה [ה] נוהגין): "נוהגין לומר ביום טוב ותערב דוקא למוסף
>   ולא ליוצר, וכן בתשב"ץ5". ומהם ליהדות אשכנז. בקובץ צפונות ב הופיע מאמר של הרב הרשלר שההדיר מכת"י
>   'קובץ מנהגי וורמייזא ומגנצא דבי רש"י ורבותיו ומנהגי אשכנז של הרוקח'.
>   הוא קובע בהקדמתו לקובץ המנהגים שהוא דומה מאד לספר 'מנהגים דבי מהר"ם'
>   ויש מקבילות רבות ביניהם. באות נז בקובץ המנהגים כתוב: 
>   "ותערב לפניך אומר החזן בכל המועדים בתפילת מוסף, וביום הכפורים בד'
>   תפילות"...
>
> ג. מתי נאמרת ברכת ותערב
>
> כתב הלבוש (או"ח סי' תפח ס"ג) בדיני פסח: "וקודם שיתחיל החזן רצה עולים
>   לדוכן, ואומר השליח צבור ברצה ותערב לפניך...ולגבי מנחה ביו"כ כתב הלבוש (או"ח סי' תרכב ס"ג): "ואין אומרין ותערב,
>   שאין נשיאת כפים במנחה". נראה שהמנהג היה להוסיף בקשת ותערב בברכת רצה ה'
>   ברכת עבודה בתפילת העמידה ואמירתה היא במוסף בלבד בימים טובים ור"ה
>   ויו"כ.
>
> ד. תלות ותערב בברכת כהנים
>
> כתב המגן אברהם (סי' קכח סוס"ק עד): "בזמן שאין שם כהן א"א ותערב (ר"ב
>   לובלין סימן ל')". וכן הובא משמו באליה רבה (סי' קכח ס"ק פט). וכן כתב אף המשנה ברורה (סי' קכח ס"ק קעג): "כתב בתשובת מהר"מ לובלין כשאין כהנים במוסף לעלות לדוכן נוהגים שאין אומרים ותערב".
>
> ולכן הלבוש כשכותב על תפילת נעילה בסימן תרכג לא מזכיר שאומרים ותערב,
>   ומסביר שאין אצלם נשיאות כפים בנעילה משום שהם מסיימים הרבה לאחר שקיעה
>   ואין נשיאות כפים בלילה. למדנו מדבריהם ש'ותערב' היא בקשה המצורפת דוקא לברכת כהנים ובחו"ל בקהילות אשכנז שהיו עולים רק במוספים אז הוסיפו בקשה זאת במוספי יו"ט ור"ה ויו"כ.
>
> וכך כתב בפסקי תשובות (או"ח סי' תרסט אות ה) לגבי ותערב בשמחת תורה:
>   "וכשאין הכהנים נושאים כפיהם במוסף אין אומר הש"ץ 'ותערב' (סי' קכ"ח מ"ב
>   ס"ק קע"ג בשם מהר"ם מלובלין, וכ"ה בלבוש סי' תפ"ח ובסידור יעב"ץ סדר
>   נשיאת כפים ליקוטי מהרי"ח בסדר יום א' דפסח), ויש אומרים שהאומרים אותו
>   אף כשאין כהנים לא הפסידו, ובחוץ לארץ בקהילות הנוהגים שהכהנים נושאים
>   כפיהם בשמח"ת בשחרית לא יאמרו 'ותערב', (לוח א"י להגרימ"ט יום א' דר"ה,
>   אך צ"ע אם יסיים נוסח הברכה 'שאותך לבדך' שאף כשיש כהנים יש המפקפקים בזה
>   עיין בליקוטי מהרי"ח שם בשם הגר"א ובפאת השלחן הל' א"י סי' ב' סעי' י"ז),
>   כי לא נתקן אלא לתפילת מוסף שאומרים בו סדר קרבן מוסף (ד"מ סי' תר"כ,
>   קיצשו"ע סי' קל"ח סעי' ח', אמנם בדרכי חיים ושלום אות ק"פ כותב לומר
>   ותערב בנשי"כ דשחרית (בחו"ל) וכ"כ בסידור כתר נהורא, ועיין שו"ת לבושי
>   מרדכי ח"ג סי' נ"ו). נראה שהאחרונים נחלקו האם להוסיף ותערב בשחרית ביום שיש בו מוסף אע"פ שלא
>   נהגו בו נשיאות כפים (בחו"ל)...
>
> ו. הקשר בין ברכת רצה לנשיאות כפים
>
> כתב הטור (או"ח סי' קכ): "ברכת י"ז רצה ותקנוה אחר שומע תפלה שכיון שבאת
>   התפלה באה עבודה דכתיב (ישעיה נה) ושמחתים בבית תפלתי עולותיהם וזבחיהם
>   לרצון על מזבחי כי ביתי בית תפלה יקרא לכל העמים... ונוהגים בספרד שלא
>   לומר רצה במנחה אלא מתחיל ואשי ישראל...ואיני יודע טעם למנהגם אף על פי שאין נשיאת כפים במנחה מה ענין זה שלא
>   לומר רצה ...
>   ובאר הבית יוסף (או"ח סי' קכ): "ונוהגים בספרד שלא לומר רצה במנחה אלא
>   מתחיל ואשי ישראל. זה לשון המנהיג (תפלה סי' נט) ראיתי בטוליטולא וכל
>   סביבותיה שאין אומרים רצה כי אם במנחת תענית ולא בשאר מנחה ומתחילין ואשי
>   ישראל ותפילתם וכו' ויראה לי הטעם כי בשעה שאין הכהנים נושאין כפיהם אין
>   לומר רצה לפי שאמרו בפרק אלו נאמרין (סוטה לח:) כל כהן שאינו עולה בעבודה
>   לדוכן שוב אינו עולה ורצה קורא עבודה דעל הקרבנות כתוב (שמות כח לח)
>   לרצון להם לפני יי' וכשמתחיל החזן רצה הם עולים לדוכן ומנחה שבכל יום אין
>   בה נשיאת כפים זולתי במנחה דתענית וכן כתב רבינו סעדיה כמנהג ספרד. אך מה
>   שכתב כי אם במנחת תענית ובמנחת יום הכפורים אף על פי שאין בה נשיאת כפים
>   אין נוהגים בזה בספרד כמוהו ולא בצרפת ובפרובינצא כי אם בשחרית ומוסף
>   ונעילה בכפורים בשעה שהיו נושאין כפיהם אבל במנחת הכפורים שלא היו נושאין
>   אין אומרים וכן בדין אך בפרובינצא ובצרפת נהגו מקרוב לומר ערבית ושחרית
>   ומנחה רצה ולא יתכן בעיני עכ"ל. ונראה שטעם רבינו סעדיה דבמנחת יום
>   הכפורים אומרים רצה אף על פי שאין בו נשיאת כפים כדי שלא לחלק במנחת
>   תענית בין זו לזו. ועכשיו בכל המקומות נוהגים לומר רצה בכל התפילות".
>
> והב"ח (או"ח סי' קכ) תרץ: "ונוהגים בספרד שלא לומר רצה במנחה וכו' ואיני
>   יודע טעם למנהגם וכו'. ולפע"ד נראה לומר טעם הגון דתקנת חכמים מתחלה כך
>   היתה שלא לומר רצה כשאין שם נשיאת כפים דבזה ידעו הכהנים אימתי יעלו
>   לדוכן דכשאומרים רצה הוא יודע דחייבים בנשיאת כפים ועוקר ממקומו מיד
>   לעלות לדוכן לישא כפיהם וכשאין אומרים רצה הוא יודע שאין שם נשיאת כפים
>   ולכן כתב רב סעדיה דמי שאומרו תמיד לא יפה עושה דאין כאן היכר ושום סימן
>   לכהנים אימתי יהיו עוקרים רגליהם ממקומם לעלות לדוכן כשאומר השליח ציבור
>   רצה כיון שאומר רצה בכל התפילות".
>
> עולה לפי הב"ח שאמירת רצה היא סימן לכהנים לעלות לדוכן ולכן רק בתפילה
>   שיש בה נ"כ אומרים רצה, ובמנחה שחששו לשכרות בטלו נ"כ וממילא אין לומר בה
>   רצה... נראה שהוספת ותערב דומה במקצת לאמירת רצה. את שניהם לא נהגו אלא בתפילה
>   שיש בה נשיאות כפים ואע"פ שלגבי רצה פסק השו"ע שחייבים לאומרו בכל תפילה
>   ותפילה ללא קשר לנ"כ, הרי תפילת ותערב לא נהגו בה אלא כשיש נשיאות כפים,
>   ואולי אף היא נהגו בה כדברי הב"ח – סימן לכהנים לעלות לדוכן.

R. Soloveitchik (*Shiurim le-Zecher Abba Mari*) explained the purpose of ותערב in a different manner, in light of his explanation of Retzei as the blessing in which prayer is transformed into sacrifice:

> שתי חלויות ישנן בתפלה: א) שיח, וכלשון הברייתא (ברכות כו, ב) לגבי תקנת
>   תפלת מנחה: "יצחק תקן תפלת מנחה שנאמר ויצא יצמק לשוח בשדה לפנות ערב
>   ואין שיחה אלא תפלה שנאמר תפלה לעני כי יעטף ולפני ה' ישפך שיחו". חלות
>   זו מושרשת בתקנת אבות. הם תקנו את התפלה כשיח האדם אל הקב"ה. ב) כקרבן;
>   ישנו קיום קרבן בתפלה. אדם מקריב את עצמו בשעה שהוא מתפלל. קיום זה נעוץ
>   בתקנת תפלות כנגד תמידים. והנה בתפלת שמנה עשרה אנו אומרים שתי ברכות
>   רצופות. "שמע קולנו" ו"רצה", אשר תוכנן, לפום ריהטא, די דומה, שהרי שתיהן
>   מבקשות קבלת התפלה: "שמע קולנו ה' א-להינו חוס ורחם עלינו וקבל ברחמים
>   וברצון את תפלתנו", "רצה ה' א-להינו בעמך ישראל ובתפלתם וכו' ואשי ישראל
>   ותפלתם באהבה תקבל ברצון וכו'". ואם כן צריך עיון, למה התקינו חז"ל שתי
>   הברכות ולא הסתפקו באחת מהן? התשובה פשוטה. ברכת "שמע קולנו חוס ורחם
>   עלינו" קשורה בתפלה כשיח, על פי הכתוב, "תפלה לעני כי יעטף ולפני ה' ישפך
>   שיחו". בברכה זו אנו מבקשים את הקב"ה לקבל את שיח שפתותינו ולרחם עלינו.
>   ברכת רצה, לעומת זאת, אינה מבקשת כלל מילוי הצרכים והמאוויים, כי אם
>   ריצוי התפלה וקבלת אשי ישראל ביחד עם התפלה . קבלת הקרבן באה לידי ביטוי
>   בברכת רצה. עד רצה התפלה היא שיח; על ידי ברכה זו הופכת התפלה לקרבן. לכן
>   קשרו חז"ל ברכת כהנים ברצה, וכמבואר בדברי ר' יהושע בן לוי (סוטה לח, ב),
>   "כל כהן שאינו עולה בעבודה שוב אינו עולה שנאמר וישא אהרן את ידיו אל העם
>   ויברכם וירד מעשות החטאת והעולה והשלמים מה להלן בעבודה אף כאן בעבודה",
>   דתיכף כשהתפלה מתרוממת לדרגת קרבן, חייב הכהן לעקור רגליו ממקומו. המנהג
>   הנפוץ בישראל כי בשעה שהש"ץ מגיע לרצה הציבור אומר, "ותערב עליך עתירתנו
>   כעולה וכקרבן" - בהרבה מקומות נוהגים לחתום במטבע העתיקה, "שאותך לבדך
>   ביראה נעבוד" (חתימת הברכה במקדש) - מראה בעליל, כי בברכת רצה משהו פלאי
>   מתרחש. שיח נהפך לקרבן, ואז עולים הכהנים לדוכן

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/551/759

Comment: Also the English summary might be more detailed...